# How to complete an alias

Tags: windows, bashrc, git-bash

I'm using git bash on my Windows and I've set up this alias:

```
alias ccd='cd ~/PhpstormProjects'
```

I can use it normally, but is there a way to make this command work?

```
ccd /project1
```

Comment: You can't. Use a function. [Passing argument to alias in bash](//stackoverflow.com/q/4060880)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As David said, there's no way to make this work **with aliases**. So I've changed it to a function. On my .bashrc, just changed:

```
alias ccd='cd ~/PhpstormProjects'
```

to

```
ccd () { cd ~/PhpstormProjects/"$@" fixed args; }
```

And it works great!

```
guilherme.ferruzzi@MLW153 MINGW64 ~
$ ccd

guilherme.ferruzzi@MLW153 MINGW64 ~/PhpstormProjects
$ ccd Contas2/dist

guilherme.ferruzzi@MLW153 MINGW64 ~/PhpstormProjects/Contas2/dist (webpack)
$
```

Comment: +1 for answering your own question instead of silently using David's hint and abandoning the question.